# Weierstrass elliptic function differential form

Tags: matlab, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

this question should be easy to answer yet I can't find the solution. I want to see how the following equation is true, when $\wp(z)$ is the Weierstrass elliptic function: $$\wp'(z)^2=4\wp(z)^3-g_2\wp(z)-g_3$$ To check it with numbers I used Matlab. The results of $\wp(z);\wp'(z);g_2;g_3$ seemed fine for me. But when I calculated the 2 sides of the mentioned differential equation, they were not equal. So I really miss something. Can someone help me pls?

```
clear all;
g2=0;
g3=0;
w1=1;
w2=2j;
z1=0.7+0.5j;
p=1/z1^2;
p1=0;
t=1000;
for m=-t:t
    for n=-t:t
       
        if ((m+n*1j)~=(0+0*1j))
            p=p+1/(z1+2*m*w1+2*n*w2)^2-1/(2*m*w1+2*n*w2)^2;
            p1=p1-2/(z1+2*m*w1+2*n*w2)^3;
            g2=g2+1/(2*m*w1+2*n*w2)^4;
            g3=g3+1/(2*m*w1+2*n*w2)^6; 
        end
    end
end
g2=60*g2;
g3=140*g3;
```

Then the following is not equal zero:
`p1^2-4*p^3+g2*p+g3`,but it should have.

Comment: You need to move the `p1=p1-2/...` outside of the range of the `if` statement. Then it works but the two sides are only approximately equal.

Comment: Somos thank you! I forgot the derivative has no divergent part. This solved me the same problem in another application as well.